# Using ProviderBase for Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Is it possible to simply inherit from ProviderBase to write a MembershipProvider, instead of inhering from System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider?

There's just so much junk in the default one, we really want something much, much simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

There is no `IMembershipProvider` interface.

The membership infrastructure requires a class derived from the abstract MembershipProvider class.

Otherwise, how would asp.net know which method to call to, for instance, GetUser?

What you are calling 'junk' are simply abstract methods that define the API.

If you do not want/need to implement a feature, just fill the stub with a `NotImplementedException`.